# ReactJS Component with "sub-components"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am quite new to ReactJS and started to make some components like this:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"row w-100 ml-0 mr-0 " + this.props.className}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve now is that this component has "sub-components" (I don't know the right word for it) like  or something similiar.

Do I have to create another component for that or is it possible to implement that in one component?

Edit:

I have this component which already has childs inside:

```
<div className="custom-card">
    <Card>
        <CardHeader onClick={this.toggle} className={"card-header " + ((!this.props.readOnly && this.props.headerCtrl) && "pt-0")}>
            <CardTitle className="card-title d-flex justify-content-between">
                <p>{this.props.title}</p>
            </CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
            <CardBody className="card-body">
                {this.props.children}
            </CardBody>
        </Collapse>
    </Card>
</div>
```

But I also want that the user can specify which component should be displayed in the cardheader. So that there can not only be a `<p>` but also a `<input>` and so on.

Comment: So... what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to Card component to be in the row? Or what?

Comment: I edited the post, maybe its better to understand now

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to hide and create some elements, when user clicks something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want multiple placeholders instead of just the one `children`. Luckily seeing as React elements are just JavaScript objects you can pass them as props.

When you have a component (`<CustomCard>`) with a render method like the one in your question (unchanged):

```
<div className="custom-card">
  <Card>
    <CardHeader onClick={this.toggle} className={"card-header " + ((!this.props.readOnly && this.props.headerCtrl) && "pt-0")}>
      <CardTitle className="card-title d-flex justify-content-between">
        <p>{this.props.title}</p>
      </CardTitle>
    </CardHeader>
    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
      <CardBody className="card-body">
        {this.props.children}
      </CardBody>
    </Collapse>
  </Card>
</div>
```

You can pass custom components for the title like so:

```
<CustomCard title={<SpecialTitle>My special title</SpecialTitle>}>
  My card body!
</CustomCard>
```

Comment: Thats pretty easy and nice, thanks! But is this way a good "coding-style"?

Comment: I believe so. There are different variants, some pass elements directly others pass a function that returns the element. React even has official documentation about this pattern: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Higher Order Components(HOCs) in order to provide custom components while keeping the other part same. A typical HOC for your use case would look like

```
const HeaderHOC = (Component) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
       render() {
           <div className="custom-card">
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader onClick={this.toggle} className={"card-header " + ((!this.props.readOnly && this.props.headerCtrl) && "pt-0")}>
                        <Component {...this.props} />
                    </CardHeader>
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
                        <CardBody className="card-body">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </CardBody>
                    </Collapse>
                </Card>
            </div>
       }
    }
}
```

When you want to use this HOC, you can do it like

```
const CardTitleComp = (props) => (
     <CardTitle className="card-title d-flex justify-content-between"><p>{props.title}</p></CardTitle>   
)

const CustomComp = HeaderHOC(CardTitleComp);
```

Comment: But how can I use this component? I need to use it like this: <CustomComp title="CardTitleControl"/>

Comment: @mantaplatte, yes you can write it as you said. Instead of CardTitle,and if you want to use CardBody you can simple create the custom component with cardBody and pass the desired props

Comment: Hm, I still don't get it how to use the HeaderHOC. If I want to use it on a page e.g. in a column like this: `<div className="col-md-3>*/Here should the component be*/</div>"` how would the syntax be?